# Standard Deviation If Statement with drop-down list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good Afternoon,

I'm creating a table which presents the average and standard deviations for a variety of metrics.  This table can be filtered by date and location where the measures were taken.  Thankfully, there is an AverageIf function, but there is no such function for standard deviation.  This is my attempt:

```
{=STDEV.S(IF(**BPMS[Location]=$M$2**, IF(BPMS[Pre Date]>=$Q$1, IF(BPMS[Pre Date]<=$Q$2, BPMS[PRE Internalizing Raw], ""), ""), ""))}
```

M2 contains a drop-down list full of locations.  One of those entries is an asterisk (*), which I would like to stand for any location.  This works for the AverageIf formula, as * is usually a stand in for any value in excel formulas, but it's not working for the above formula.  How can I write the formula to allow for a specific locations OR any location?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: try this[untested] `=STDEV.S(IF((IF($M$2= "*",1,(BPMS[Location]=$M$2)))*(BPMS[Pre Date]>=$Q$1)*(BPMS[Pre Date]<=$Q$2), BPMS[PRE Internalizing Raw]))`

Comment: Looks like it works, I'll double check the math in the morning.  Thanks!